# How to deal with boss who assigns a second project without much information?

Tags: india, job-description

I am in a startup company **in India**, where my first major project is a Govt. based project. I was very much dedicated in that project. However, recently, my boss assigned another project (on top of my first),to be done using PHP/Laravel, and asked me to do it in two days' time. Of course, it was doable . My boss said that the design team will give me more information on the same.

But, when I asked the design team to give me information on the project, they said they didn't know anything, and had randomly designed two to three pages. The design team also does not know the project lead or the manager (who might be useful for more info).

Moreover, the boss and the design team are sending me information/designs at around 4 pm or 6 pm, even when my office time ends at 7 pm. Mostly the information comes on Friday, during those times.

Is it normal to handle more than one project at a time like this, for a developer? How do I deal with this situation?

Comment: Have you tried going back to your boss to communicate your issues and seek more information?

Comment: Yes, in the world of business, multiple projects at the same time, poor communication, poor co-ordination, and poor timing are all normal.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I haven't  . But I talked to some friends, and they say such poor management is too common

Comment: @B.Ithica Normal?? Are you insane? That _is_ the standard, mostly if you're in India. :)

Comment: @Skumar, It seems that this kind of things happens a lot for startups. I hope you can bounce your questions and ideas with your teammates, team lead, and managers because that is the only way to get the projects moving in startups. Usually, startups do not have enough workers (or dedicated project managers).

Answer (score 3):

It is not uncommon to deal with multiple projects/tasks at a time.

It is not uncommon for there to be poor communication/information regarding projects/tasks.

In your case, there seems to have been some sort of miscommunication or non-communication somewhere down the line.  If you did not already reach out to your design team *in writing* that would be your first step.  Next you can speak to your boss about what you have encountered:

> Hey boss, I reached out to the design team like you asked me to and they told me that they don't know anything about the project.  How should I proceed to gather information about this project?

After that you follow his direction.  Make sure all communication with any one involved is in writing so that you and your boss definitively know who said what.